# Init a Metal texture with the type of 3D

Tags: ios, swift, scenekit, metal

Recently, I am playing with SceneKit, I found the colorGrading property. The doc say that

> The contents value for this material property must be a 3D color
>   lookup table, or a 2D texture image that represents such a table
>   arranged in a horizontal strip.

and a 3D color lookup table can read from a Metal texture.

> You can provide data in this cubic format as a Metal texture with the type3D texture type.

so how can I set `scnCamera.colorGrading.contents` property.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Creating a 3D texture is very similar to creating a 2D texture, provided you have a buffer containing the image data in the appropriate layout. I assume you already have that. Here's how to create the texture itself, copy the data into it, and set it as the color grading texture:

```
var dim = 16

var values: UnsafeMutablePointer<Float> = ... // alloc and populate 3D array of pixels

let textureDescriptor = MTLTextureDescriptor()
textureDescriptor.textureType = .type3D
textureDescriptor.pixelFormat = .rgba32Float
textureDescriptor.width = dim
textureDescriptor.height = dim
textureDescriptor.depth = dim
textureDescriptor.usage = .shaderRead

let texture = device.makeTexture(descriptor: textureDescriptor)

texture.replace(region: MTLRegionMake3D(0, 0, 0, dim, dim, dim),
                mipmapLevel:0,
                slice:0,
                withBytes:values,
                bytesPerRow:dim * MemoryLayout<Float>.size * 4,
                bytesPerImage:dim * dim * MemoryLayout<Float>.size * 4)

camera.colorGrading.contents = texture
```

**EDIT**

Here's a complete parser that will turn a .cube file into a `MTLTexture` that is suitable for use with this property:

```
import Metal

class AdobeLUTParser {

    static func texture(withContentsOf url: URL, device: MTLDevice) -> MTLTexture? {

        let lutString = try! NSString(contentsOf: url, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)

        let lines = lutString.components(separatedBy: "\r\n") as [NSString]

        var dim = 2

        var values: UnsafeMutablePointer<Float>? = nil
        var index = 0

        for line in lines {

            if line.length == 0 { continue; } // skip blanks

            let firstChar = line.character(at: 0)

            if firstChar < 58 /*':'*/ {
                if values == nil {
                    print("Error: Got data before size in LUT")
                    break;
                }

                let numbers = line.components(separatedBy: " ") as [NSString]
                if numbers.count == 3 {
                    let r = numbers[0].floatValue
                    let g = numbers[1].floatValue
                    let b = numbers[2].floatValue
                    let a = Float(1)

                    values![index * 4 + 0] = r
                    values![index * 4 + 1] = g
                    values![index * 4 + 2] = b
                    values![index * 4 + 3] = a

                    index += 1
                }
            } else {
                if line.hasPrefix("LUT_3D_SIZE") {
                    let sizeString = line.components(separatedBy: " ")[1] as NSString
                    dim = Int(sizeString.intValue)
                    if dim < 2 || dim > 512 {
                        print("Error: insane LUT size: \(dim)")
                    }
                    let rawPointer = malloc(dim * dim * dim * 4 * MemoryLayout<Float>.size)
                    values = rawPointer!.bindMemory(to: Float.self, capacity: dim * dim * dim * 4)
                } else if line.hasPrefix("LUT_1D_SIZE") {
                    print("Error: 1D LUTs not supported")
                    break
                }
            }
        }

        if values == nil {
            print("Did not parse LUT successfully")
            return nil
        }

        let textureDescriptor = MTLTextureDescriptor()
        textureDescriptor.textureType = .type3D
        textureDescriptor.pixelFormat = .rgba32Float
        textureDescriptor.width = dim
        textureDescriptor.height = dim
        textureDescriptor.depth = dim
        textureDescriptor.usage = .shaderRead

        let texture = device.makeTexture(descriptor: textureDescriptor)

        texture.replace(region: MTLRegionMake3D(0, 0, 0, dim, dim, dim),
                        mipmapLevel:0,
                        slice:0,
                        withBytes:values!,
                        bytesPerRow:dim * MemoryLayout<Float>.size * 4,
                        bytesPerImage:dim * dim * MemoryLayout<Float>.size * 4)

        return texture
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
let mtlDevice = MTLCreateSystemDefaultDevice()

let lutURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "MyGradingTexture", withExtension: "cube")

let lutTexture = AdobeLUTParser.texture(withContentsOf: lutURL!, device: mtlDevice!)

camera.colorGrading.contents = lutTexture
```

Comment: Oh no... The doc say that there are two ways to set this property. one is giving a square image , one is 3D color lookup table. I search for 3D color lookup table and download some .cube files. I think if I can set these file to this colorGrading. But the doc say that should use Metal. I don't accurately understand how to do it.

Comment: I always got the error `Error: Got data before size in LUT
Did not parse LUT successfully`

Comment: It sounds like your cube file is malformed, but I wasn't able to download it before the link expired.

Comment: Thanks, It work well now. But I got the bad effect. It seems like a bug or the .cube file problem. I post a new question, check it out. [Work inside colorGrading Property](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42544724/work-inside-colorgrading-property)

Comment: `let rawPointer = malloc(dim * dim * dim * 4 * MemoryLayout<Float>.size)`
Why is it `*4` when this a 3d cube (width x height x depth) ?

Comment: Because there are four components (RGBA) per pixel.

Comment: It looks like iOS does not support to sample a RGBA32Float texture with a sampler with a linear filter. How can I convert this texture into a texture that will work on iOS?

Comment: It's a bit trickier, but you should be able to use a 16-bit per component texture instead (`.rgba16Float`), without a noticeable loss in precision. If you're using Swift 5.3, you can use the `Float16` type directly. Otherwise, you can use the `__fp16` type provided by Clang.

Comment: Thanks for the .cube to MTLTexture convert, but I still not clear How to convert a .3dl file to MTLTexture, can someone write an example for me? Thanks very much.

Comment: .3DL is a completely different file format. You should post a new question if you don't know how to convert or parse it.

Comment: @warrenm Hi, I have post a new question in this link, Thanks very much if you know how to convert it. [Convert .3dl to Metal texture](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74840242/convert-a-3dl-file-to-metal-texture)