# Work inside colorGrading property?

Tags: ios, scenekit

Does anybody use colorGrading property of the SCNCamera to adjust rendered colors?  **The colorGrading's contents value must be a 3D color lookup table(LUT) or a 2D texture image the represents such a table arranged in a horzontal strip.** So I try to download some 3D color lookup table file whic is .cube format and write some Metal code. But when I run it, I got the whole black scene. But when I move the camera, the black disappear but the colorGranding didn't work that way. So I want to use 2D texture image, but I couldn't find the resources from the internet. **The doc says the you can create a basic color table image to create custom effects.** ***But what does it mean? How can I create a basic color table image?***

Comment: Pleas add more details, consider attaching your LUT file here and the output you are getting over the given input. This can help us identify the problem